# What is this algebraic operation called?

Tags: matrices

What is the name of the algebraic operation shown below. My teacher calls this finding a linear mapping matrix in a canonical basis. However, when I google it, I can't find anything similar.

$A: R^2 \rightarrow R^3$

$A(x,y)=(2x+3y,-x+5y,x+0y)$

$A(1,0)=(2*1+3*0,-1+5*0,1+0*0)$

$A(0,1)=(2*0+3*1,-0+5*1,0+0*1)$

$A(1,0)=(\color{blue}{\textrm{2,-1,1}})$

$A(0,1)=(\color{orange}{\textrm{3,5,0}})$

$A\simeq \begin{bmatrix}\color{blue}{2}&\color{orange}3\\\color{blue}{-1}&\color{orange}5\\\color{blue}{1}&\color{orange}0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: There isn't a name for it so much as it is a concept. A linear map is completely determined by its action on the basis elements. In this case your teacher is using the standard basis. Later in the course you will be taught how to express the same linear map with a different basis.

Comment: I'd call it the matrix associated to the map $A$ with respect to the standard bases.

Comment: What you mentioned is the name. They are finding the [transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) of $A$ in the basis $(1,0), (0,1)$, which some people call it "canonical".

Comment: "evaluation (the linear transformation) on the canonical basis"

Comment: Look up the “standard matrix” (of a linear map).